# Error when updating Manjaro with pamac: snapd already present on file system

Tags: package-management, manjaro, software-updates, snap

Yesterday, i wanted to get install updates using the pamac updater.
I got an error saying something along the lines of

```
files in conflict: snapd-git: /snap already exists in file system.
```

Since I am running Manjaro with the german language option, this is not exactly the message but i suppose it should be similar in english.

Now what i did first was un-checking it for update, but now i still get the update notification only about the package snapd-git.

I am unsure what my actual problem is:

- either the update is unnecessary in which case i'd like to get rid of the notification
- or I have an old version installed and have to manually remove it and install the current version.

I do not know if snapd gets used from any other applications, so i figured I'd ask here first before removing anything critical.

It would be appreciated if anybody could help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From; https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/snapd#Removal

> Uninstalling the snapdAUR package will not remove directories and
>   files created while using snap. It's best to remove your snaps with
>   snap remove before uninstalling the package. At this time it is not
>   possible to remove the core snap through the snap command. To remove
>   the state, snap package cache and mount unit files completely, you can
>   follow the instructions below.
>
> 1. We unmount any currently active snap that is mounted to /var/lib/snapd/snap/.
>
> `# umount $(mount | grep snap | awk '{print $3}')`
>
> 2. We remove the state directory and mount hook.
>
> `# rm -rf /var/lib/snapd`
>   `# rm -rf /var/snap`
>
> 3. We remove any unit files, that try to mount snaps from /var/lib/snapd/snaps to /var/lib/snapd/snap at boot.
>
> `# find /etc/systemd/system -name "*snap-*.mount" -delete`
>   `# find /etc/systemd/system -name "snap.*.service" -delete`

You will have to do these unmounts, and reinstall snap from AUR using `# yaourt snapd`.

Then resume system updates as normally.

Comment: The first step does not seem to work on my machine, i get an error saying "incorrect usage of umount".

Comment: Removing

Snaps can be removed by executing:

# snap remove snapname